# MySQL - insert / update / delete in views

Tags: mysql, view, alias

I have a website in english and in french.

So in my database, my tables have column named "name_english" and "name_french" for example and some other numeric columns.

I want to create 2 views, or something like this, that will have the column "name" and all the other columns of my table.

The view "table_english" will have the column "name_english" as "name" and the view "table_french" will have the column "name_french" as "name".

This is working fine with views on selects, but I also want to make some inserts/updates/deletes on views that will update the table.

Example:

```
table:
id | name_english | name_french | int1 | int2 | int3

table_english (a view):
id | name | int1 | int2 | int3 (name here is name_english)

table_french (a view):
id | name | int1 | int2 | int3 (name here is name_french)
```

Then I want to do some queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_english(id, name, int1, int2, int3) VALUES (1, 'name', 12, 14, 2);
UPDATE table_english set name='new name' WHERE id=1;
```

And these will be inserted/updated in the table with the corresponding fields.

So At the end, the content of "table" will be:

```
1 | 'new name' | DEFAULT VALUE | 12 | 14 | 2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It's very odd that you are trying to internationalize your site this way. You might want to consider having this logic in the application itself and switch between databases. If it's strictly view related you should look into gettext. Maybe some more information about why you've chosen this approach might be helpful in getting a better answer.

Comment: my application have this logic. But users can add some content and this content can be translated. If I use 2 databases, I will have to replicate all operations on both database to have the exact same database except for text fields.

Comment: So have a column in the table to indicate whether it's english or french and the application can filter results based on that.

Comment: But I already have the website in english I don't want to pass through all queries in my code to change that. I just wnated to change the table name, like I can do with view. Because I have the table names in variables. But if it is impossible, I will do it the hard way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A view can be updatable and insertable if it follows certain guidelines.

[More information here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html)

The short version is: You can't update a view that has any kind of GROUP BY, DISTINCT or Aggregate functions. There are more restrictions, but the manual is you best bet for up to date information on those.

Comment: From mysql website: "A view that has a mix of simple column references and derived columns is not insertable, but it can be updatable if you update only those columns that are not derived." I want to insert / update derived column.

Comment: Which columns are derived? From your example, they all seem to be references.

Comment: My view is created like this: CREATE VIEW table_english AS SELECT id,name_english AS name, int1, int2, int3 FROM table

Comment: Those are only references, so you should be able to update and insert. From the manual: `The view columns must be simple column references and not derived columns. A derived column is one that is not a simple column reference but is derived from an expression.`

Answer (score 1):

You can insert/update a view. The purpose of a view is to show the full or partial status of one or more table. You will have to update the table and have two updates and two inserts... one that updates/inserts `name_english` column and one for `name_french` column.

Comment: From mysql website: "A view that has a mix of simple column references and derived columns is not insertable, but it can be updatable if you update only those columns that are not derived." I want to insert / update derived column.